# How to make Javascript Timeout function run even when browser is running in background?

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer, timeout

I tried making a Timer with the help of vanilla JavaScript and used Timeout Function to update the timer milliseconds every millisecond but after starting it, if I switch to another application other than my current browser, timeout function stops executing it.
If I left the window focus for 8 seconds and then after some seconds I come back on the browser, the timer continues from 8 seconds.
I want it to run even in the background continuously.

I also thought that this might help, but I didn't know how to implement this - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_api_web_workers.asp

Comment: Use date object to track time.... Never rely on timers for time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all modern browsers by design don't allow JS execution if the tab isn't focused, that's by design for optimization purposes.

You can use workers to have code that still can run even if the tab loses focus, but workers are not allowed to access the DOM so you can't make any visible update on the page.

Here's a simple example:
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="startWorker()">Start Worker</button>
<button onclick="stopWorker()">Stop Worker</button>

<script>
let w;

function startWorker() {
  if (typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
    if (typeof(w) == "undefined") {
      w = new Worker("webWorker.js");
    } 
  }  
}

function stopWorker() {
  w.terminate();
  w = undefined;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

webWorker.js

```
let max = 0 

let consoleLogWorker = () => {
  console.log("background log")
  max+= 1
  if(max < 50) setTimeout("consoleLogWorker()",500);
 
}

consoleLogWorker();
```

If you run the above example you will see once you start the worker even if you navigate away from the page that started the worker, it will still print in the console.

But again you can't directly access the DOM in the web worker.

You should try using *Via.js* that lets you access the DOM 'inside' the worker, it wasn't such a viable solution in the past because it created memory leaks, but WeakRefs are enabled by default in Chrome 84+ so it should not create memory leaks on newer browsers.

I used via to create a chrome extension that set timers in the backgrounds and then changes the icon of websites using web workers here is the source https://gitlab.flashsoft.eu/chrome-extensions/tab-timer-alert maybe it will help you.